# IE Visited Link is showing inverted backcolor

Tags: css

Visited links in IE 11 are showing up "inverted" with a dark blue background and a white foreground. I'm no CSS expert by any stretch, but my understanding is that this should cause visited and unvisited to look the same at all times.

```
a:link, a:visited {color: #034af3;}
```

Here is what it is doing (IE only)

[image]

That dark background is exactly the background-color of my ASP.Net Menu control.  To get around this IE issue, I went to the .main definition in my CSS and forced the background-color to #ffffff for visited links.

```
.main a:visited {background-color: #ffffff;}
```

Everything seemed great until I looked at a page where I have AllowSorting set to "true" on my gridview.  Now those links in the Header row have a white background, so by solving one issue with a hack I have created another issue.

Is there a way to block this "bluing" issue with IE and visited links?

========================

## EDIT - Adding New Info:

I have changed the CSS for the navigation menu.  I had originally set the "a item" (visited, hover, etc.) background color for each definition to #3a4f63, but spurred by Christoph's question below, changed those to "inherit" so, if I understand correctly, those now inherit from the hideSkiplink div which also has a background of #3a4f63. The menu still displays correctly, and this change also affected links in the body of the page.  The result of that change is seen in the image below.  So, clearly the definitions for my menu are affecting links in the main body of the page.

The forecolor is still inverted (almost white) but the backcolor is not being inverted to the dark blue.

[image]

Comment: You could try `transparent` or `inherit` as values.

Comment: What version of IE is this?

Comment: Chuks, this is IE 11.

Comment: Christoph, I am assuming you mean setting those values as background-color in the a:visited?  If so, I tried both, and have the same inversion effect on visited links.

Comment: New info:  I'll add to initial question momentarily.

Comment: @DJGray can you make sure to set all of the 4 states, and in this order? a:link {} a:visited {} a:hover {} a:active{}

Comment: Got it.  I am not certain which change specifically resolved the issue, but it is now behaving exactly as I want it to.  Apparently CSS is fairly tempermental!!  ;-)   Thanks to ALL for your helpful suggestions in sleuthing this out.

Comment: @DJGray well, take a look  - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp if you're willing to learn more.